# Inner product on a positive-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$, be a positive-definite matrix, $x=(x_1,\cdots,c_n)$,$y=(y_1,\cdots,cy_n)$. How do we prove that $$\langle x,y\rangle = x^TAy$$ is a inner product?

I know that $\langle x,x\rangle > 0$ it's easy to prove. For the other conditions, my attempt is $$\langle x,y \rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n y_i(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_i) $$

if this equality is true, i can easily prove the conditions.

There is an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What definition do you use for positive-definiteness of matrices? The usual one basically coincides with the positivity condition for the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show

1. linearity in the first argument
2. Conjugate symmetry
3. positive-definite

(1) follows from the linearity of matrix multiplication: $(x+z)^TAy=x^TAy+z^TAy$

(2) follows from the property of matrix transpose:
$$
x^TAy=(x^TAy)^T=y^TA^Tx=y^TAx
$$

You said you have done (3).